# Iterate on a tMssqlInput in Talend

Tags: talend

I use the last version of Talend 5.3.1.

I have a tmssqlInput which query my database like :

```
SELECT IdInvoice, DateInvoice, IdStuff, Name FROM Invoice
INNER JOIN Stuff ON Invoice.IdInvoice = Stuff.IdInvoice
```

which result in something like this

```
IdInvoice    | DateInvoice | IdStuff    | Name
1            | 2013-01-01  | 10         | test
1            | 2013-01-01  | 11         | test2
2            | 2013-02-01  | 12         | test3
2            | 2013-02-01  | 13         | test4
```

I'd like to export **one file per invoice**, here the specifications :
one header line with IdInvoice;DateInvoice
then one line per stuff like IdStuff;Name

example file 1:

```
1;2013-01-01
10;test
11;test2
```

example file 2 :

```
2;2013-02-01
12;test3
13;test4
```

how can I resolve that case with talend ?
Probably in tFileOutputDelimited but how can I have one file with multiple informations and iterate over each IdInvoice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go through the following link, you will get clear idea how to split data into multiple files
http://www.talendfreelancer.com/2013/09/talend-tflowtoiterate.html